# Creating a Node NPM module in 9.2.0 to support older versions of Node

Tags: node.js, npm

Now that Node 9.2.0 has all the new features of the language, how do I go about creating a node module that is backwards compatible with older versions?

If I have a small module that Node 9 supports out of the box, like this.

```
const {map} = require('lodash')

async function test (...args) {
    return map(args, (item) => {
        return `${item} yeah`
    })
}

module.exports = test
```

Are there any was to use babel to transpile this for the specific backward version that I would need to support using babel env? Is there any way I can conditionally load those babel development dependencies, say installing this via Node 4 using post-install scripts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is one solution one downside of which is it requires `babel-runtime` as a dep just in case, even if the current version of node doesn't need it. But in 9.2.0 the code above is the built code, it's simply moved by babel.

Here's an example package.json and on install it will build the src.

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-runtime"
    ],
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```